# UITableView Destructive Context Menu Animation

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I'm adding iOS13 context menus to my table view.  One of the menu actions allows the user to delete the item:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, contextMenuConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, point: CGPoint) -> UIContextMenuConfiguration? {
    return UIContextMenuConfiguration(identifier: nil, previewProvider: nil) { suggestedActions in
       let deleteAction = UIAction(title: "Delete", image: UIImage(systemName: "trash.fill"), identifier: nil, discoverabilityTitle: "", attributes: UIMenuElement.Attributes.destructive) { action in
            self.data.remove(at: indexPath.row)

            //Remove from the table.
            self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        }

        return UIMenu(title: "", children: [deleteAction])
    }
}
```

I'm using the default preview view controller (so it just shows the cell).  I'm currently seeing a weird animation artifact where the context menu preview is displayed while the items below the row being removed animated up, then the preview fades away to white (so it looks like there is a blank row in the list), then the table repaints and displays the item that was covered up.
[image]

This is using the default cell but it looks a lot worse when using a customized cell with a lot more information.  Is there anyway to make this action animate better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into this problem as well. The bug is probably due to the fact that the original cell used to generate the preview was deleted, moved or changed.

The solution I found was to implement the delegate method `tableView(_:previewForHighlightingContextMenuWithConfiguration:)`, passing it the original cell as the view, but customising `UIPreviewParameters` to use `UIColor.clear`:

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, previewForHighlightingContextMenuWithConfiguration configuration: UIContextMenuConfiguration) -> UITargetedPreview? {
        guard let indexPath = configuration.identifier as? IndexPath, let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) else {
            return nil
        }
        
        let parameters = UIPreviewParameters()
        parameters.backgroundColor = .clear
        
        return UITargetedPreview(view: cell, parameters: parameters)
    }
```

In order to identify the original cell in this delegate method, you'd need a way to identify it. One way is to set the `indexPath` as the identifier to `UIContextMenuConfiguration`, like:

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, contextMenuConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, point: CGPoint) -> UIContextMenuConfiguration? {
        return UIContextMenuConfiguration(identifier: indexPath as NSIndexPath, previewProvider: nil) { _ in
            return UIMenu(title: "", children: [
                UIAction(title: "Delete", image: UIImage(systemName: "trash"), attributes: .destructive) { action in
                    self.data.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                    tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
                }
            ])
        }
    }
```

However if your data can change between the presentation of the context menu and the action, then you need a more robust way to identify it.

I did not have to implement `tableView(_:previewForDismissingContextMenuWithConfiguration:)` for this to work.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me on iOS 14.3. For both, `previewForHighlightingContextMenuWithConfiguration` or `UIContextMenuConfiguration.previewProvider` with custom VC I get the exact same behavior as in OP's GIF. :(

Comment: My bad I guess. I had to implement the `previewForDismissingContextMenuWithConfiguration` instead, because I am using a custom `previewProvider`. It works perfectly now! Thanks!

Comment: Facing the same issue... My collectionView listens to socket changes, so it updates quite frequently... I get weird animations...SOS

Answer (score 0):

If you update your `UITableView` directly in the action, the background color drawn behind your cell as part of the preview will still be visible where your cell used to be. The proper way to handle this is to wait for the context menu to dismiss completely before performing any actions on the table view:

```swift
private var indexPathToDelete: IndexPath?

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
                        contextMenuConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, 
                        point: CGPoint) -> UIContextMenuConfiguration? {
        return UIContextMenuConfiguration(actionProvider: { _ in
            let action = UIAction(
                title: "Delete",
                image: UIImage(systemName: "trash"), 
                attributes: .destructive) { [weak self] _ in
                    self?.indexPathToDelete = indexPath
                }
            return UIMenu(children: [action])
        }
    }

override func tableView(_ tableView: 
                        willEndContextMenuInteraction configuration: UIContextMenuConfiguration,
                        animator: UIContextMenuInteractionAnimating?) {
    animator?.addCompletion { [weak self] in
        guard let self,
              let indexPathToDelete = self.indexPathToDelete else {
            return
        }
        self.data.remove(at: indexPathToDelete.row)
        self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPathToDelete], with: .automatic)
        self.indexPathToDelete = nil
    }
}
```

Of course, this will cause a noticeable delay to your table view update.